# Java - How to pass XML request body in rest post method

Tags: java

I need to make an api call rest POST method by passing XML request body. I achieved the same through VB.net. In VB.net I used `XElement` to pass request body.

For example:

```
Dim xml As XElement = <Request xmlns="request"><ID>181</ID><Password>String content</Password><Service>service name</Service><UserName>username</UserName></Request>.
```

In Java how to pass the above XML request body to call rest post method.

Comment: Use  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

Comment: For passing xml request body in post method you have to write MediaType.APPLICATION_XML as @Good Bad and Ugly said. For this purpose you can use Rest client add-on of mozila firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            String url = "pass your url";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/xml;charset=utf-8");
            String urlParameters = "<Request xmlns=\"abc\"><ID>1</ID><Password></Password></Request>";
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println("response:" + response.toString());


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is sample code of how to do it, or you can find some Java library, such as `commons-httpclient`, which would be easier than this.

```
 String xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='gb2312'?>"
                + "<Req>"
                + "<EventContentReq>"
                + "<EventID>101</EventID >"
                + "</EventContentReq>"
                + "</Req>";

        byte[] xmlData = xmlString.getBytes();

        String urlStr = "http://124.128.62.164:7001/test";

        DataInputStream input = null;

        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();

            urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
            urlCon.setDoInput(true);
            urlCon.setUseCaches(false);


            urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(xmlData.length));

            input = new DataInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
            out = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] bufferByte = new byte[256];
            int l = -1;

            while ((l = input.read(bufferByte)) > -1) {
                out.write(bufferByte, 0, l);
                out.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                out.close();

                input.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you. when I tried the above code I got 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405.
Then I changed the URLConnection to HttpURLConnection. now I am getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411.
Eventhough the content length is passed along with the request, I am getting this error

Comment: I am getting 405 exception in this line
   input = new DataInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());

Comment: Please check if the URL and XML content is correct?

Comment: Hi jerry, I tried some otherway and got success response. Thank you